# Ns2 procedure loop

Tags: tcl, ns2

### Actually, I'm new in simulation project that I want to call another procedure from the following procedure:

```
#call
source costtest1.tcl
for { set x 5} { $x <6} { incr x } {
input_Protocol_pramerters 20 $x 2.0 $x
}
puts "Done"
```

-

### The other procedure includes the following DSR protocol to generate the performance evaluation for simulation scenario

```
proc input_Protocol_pramerters {No_node No_connaction Rate iter} {
set cbr "cbr-"
set secn "scan-" 
append cbr $iter
append secn $iter
set DSR_fileTr "DSR"
append DSR_fileTr $iter ".tr"
set DSR_fileNam "DSR"
append DSR_fileNam $iter ".nam"
puts $iter
        #---- Generate Movement file ----
puts [eval exec "./setdest -v 1 -n $No_node -p 5 -M $No_connaction -t 100 -x 1000 -y 1000 >$secn"]      
        #---- Generate Movement file ----
puts [eval exec "ns cbrgen.tcl -type cbr -nn $No_node -seed 1.0 -mc $No_connaction -rate $Rate >$cbr"]

    #---- Main simulation file to generate DSR.tr and DSR.nam
    #----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Definition of the physical layer
    #----------------------------------------------------------------
    set val(chan)       Channel/WirelessChannel
    set val(prop)       Propagation/TwoRayGround
    set val(netif)      Phy/WirelessPhy
    set val(mac)        Mac/802_11
    set val(ifq)        CMUPriQueue 
    set val(ll)         LL
    set val(ant)        Antenna/OmniAntenna
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Scenario parameters
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    set val(x)              1500   ;# X dimension of the topography
    set val(y)              1500   ;# Y dimension of the topography
    set val(ifqlen)         50    ;# max packet in queue
    set val(seed)           1.0    ;#random seed            
    set val(adhocRouting)   DSR
    set val(nn)             $No_node ;# how many nodes are simulated
    set val(cp)             $cbr 
    set val(sc)             $secn 
    set val(stop)           50       ;# simulation time
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #  Set up simulator objects                  
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # create simulator instance
    set ns_     [new Simulator]
    # setup topography object
    set topo    [new Topography]
    # create trace object for ns and nam
    set tracefd [open $DSR_fileTr w]
    $ns_ use-newtrace  ;# use the new wireless trace file format
    set namtrace    [open $DSR_fileNam w]

    $ns_ trace-all $tracefd
    $ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)
    # define topology
    $topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
    # Create God
    set god_ [create-god $val(nn)]
    $ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(adhocRouting) \
                 -llType $val(ll) \
                 -macType $val(mac) \
                 -ifqType $val(ifq) \
                 -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
                 -antType $val(ant) \
                 -propType $val(prop) \
                 -phyType $val(netif) \
                 -channelType $val(chan) \
                     -topoInstance $topo \
                     -agentTrace ON \
                 -routerTrace ON \
                 -macTrace ON
    #  Create the specified number of nodes [$val(nn)] and "attach" them
    #  to the channel. 
    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
        set node_($i) [$ns_ node]   
        $node_($i) random-motion 0      ;# disable random motion
    }

    # Define node movement model
    puts "Loading connection pattern..."
    source $val(cp)
    # Define traffic model
    puts "Loading scenario file..."
    source $val(sc)

    # Define node initial position in nam
    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {
    # 50 defines the node size in nam, must adjust it according to your  scenario
        # The function must be called after mobility model is defined
        # puts "Processing node $i"
        $ns_ initial_node_pos $node_($i) 50
    }
    #
    # Tell nodes when the simulation ends
    #
    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
        $ns_ at $val(stop).0 "$node_($i) reset";
    }

    $ns_ at  $val(stop).0002 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"

    # dump the initial simulation info to the trace file

    puts $tracefd "M 0.0 nn $val(nn) x $val(x) y $val(y) rp $val(adhocRouting)"
    puts $tracefd "M 0.0 sc $val(sc) cp $val(cp) seed $val(seed)"
    puts $tracefd "M 0.0 prop $val(prop) ant $val(ant)"

    puts "Starting Simulation..."
    $ns_ run
    # end Mail file 
# Evaluate parametrs
puts [eval exec "awk -f End2endDelay_RoutingPackets.awk $DSR_fileTr"]
}
```

-

### In the first call, I got the results

```
5


num_nodes is set 20
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
Loading connection pattern...
Loading scenario file...
Starting Simulation...
channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 550.0
SORTING LISTS ...DONE!
NS EXITING...
Packet Sent = 136.00
Packet Receive = 82.00
routingpkts = 123.00
Packet Delivery Ratio = 60.29
NRL = 1.50
Average end-to-end Delay (ms)= 13219.08
No. of dropped data (packets) = 21
No. of dropped data (bytes)   = 11172
```

-

### In the second iteration, I got the following error

```
6


num_nodes is set 20
invalid command name "_o491 _o4"
    while executing
"$ns_ get-nodetype"
    (procedure "_o501" line 22)
    (Object next line 22)
    invoked from within
"_o501 next"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self next $args"
    (procedure "_o501" line 3)
    (Object next line 3)
    invoked from within
"_o501 next"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self next $args  "
    (procedure "_o501" line 6)
    (SRNodeNew init line 6)
    invoked from within
"_o501 init "
    (Class create line 1)
    invoked from within
"SRNodeNew create _o501 "
    invoked from within
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
delete $o
return ""
}
global errorInfo
error "class $..."
    (procedure "new" line 3)
    invoked from within
"new SRNodeNew"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval new $nodeclass $args"
    (procedure "_o491" line 8)
    (Simulator create-node-instance line 8)
    invoked from within
"_o491 create-node-instance"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self create-node-instance $args"
    (procedure "_o491" line 6)
    (Simulator create-wireless-node line 6)
    invoked from within
"_o491 create-wireless-node"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self create-wireless-node $args"
    (procedure "_o491" line 23)
    (Simulator node line 23)
    invoked from within
"$ns_ node"
    (procedure "input_Protocol_pramerters" line 61)
    invoked from within
"input_Protocol_pramerters 20 6 2.0 6"
    (file "call.tcl" line 5)
```

-

Comment: Missing? : `costtest1.tcl` → Not really clear what's going on unless you show or upload missing files.

Comment: @KnudLarsen this file (costtest1.tcl) contain the code above [the procedure]:
(
proc input_Protocol_pramerters {No_node No_connaction Rate iter} {
set cbr "cbr-"
.
.
)
which i call it from the file (call.tcl) which contain this code (
#call
source costtest1.tcl
for { set x 5} { $x <6} { incr x } {
input_Protocol_pramerters 20 $x 2.0 $x
}
puts "Done"
)